# Rename a column with space in it

Tags: sql, postgresql

Someone mistakenly created a table in which all the column names has a leading space in it. For example: 'accountid' is now ' accountid'.

I am going to write a SQL statement to rename these columns. The one I wrote is:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME COLUMN ' accountid' TO 'accountid';
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "' accountid'"
```

Can someone instruct me how to rename these? How to change my statement to make it runnable? I use PostgreSQL.

Many thanks.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you need double quotes when referring to column names.

Answer (score 7):

In PostgreSQL, you use double-quotes for identifiers (if necessary): `"`

```
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME COLUMN " accountid" TO "accountid";
```

[See here and browse to 4.1.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one does solved the above problem. However, it gives another error: <Error : ERROR:  column " accountid" does not exist>. The column definitely exists. What is the problem? Many thanks.

Comment: can you provide the schema of the tables? :D

Comment: CREATE TABLE mytable
(
  " accountid" bigint NOT NULL,
  " enabled" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  " rowid" bigserial NOT NULL
)

Comment: @KZhang , weired, it works on SQLFiddle. [Click here for demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a46e93/3)

Comment: @KZhang: Are you sure you only used one space not several spaces or some other whitespace characters?

Comment: @JohnWoo: The double quote is not an "escape character". It's the SQL way of quoting names and makes the term inside atomic. My standing advise is to use lower case legal names without special characters **only**, so you don't have to double quote to begin with. This question goes to show, why. Also, don't link to outdated versions of the manual! 8.2 is not supported any more. [Link to the current version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108714/169168). I fixed the link. Finally, double quotes are optional around the second instance of `accountid` (without space) because it's a legal name.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for that. Actually I used that word just like any other rdbms termed it. but thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

You can even put other characters:

```
select c.comment "actor.comment"  from post p join comment c on p.id = c.post_id;
```